# Proving that $f(x,y) = (e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$ is neither surjective nor injective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This question is useful in my real analysis quiz and I am struck on this.

> Prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y) = (e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$ is not a surjective map.

I tried to get an intution by drawing graph and I think that it must be surjective as $0<e^x<\infty$ and $-1\leq \sin y,\, \cos y \leq 1$ so , every value can be attained by multiplication.  But, answer is given that it is not surjective.

Edit : I think I also need help with injectivity. Let $f(x,y) =(0,0)$ which implies that $\cos y =0$ and $\sin y =0$, whose solution is $\left\{\phi\right\}$. By definition, if $f$ is injective then only solutions of $f(x,y)=(0,0)$, taking contrapositive I get that solutions such that $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ implies that $f(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ which is satisfied. So, $f(x,y)$ is injective also.

But the answer is that it is not injective.

Kindly help with that.

Comment: Hint: check if $(0,0)$ is in the range of $f$.

Comment: Use the periods of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Check whats $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,y+2k\pi)$ where $k$ is an integer

Comment: What is $\phi$? Do you mean $\emptyset$?

Comment: @Gary Ya, I mean empty set

Comment: @No-One What does it mean for the solution to be the empty set?

Comment: Can accept only 1 answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For injectivity suppose
$$ e^x \cos y = e^u\cos v \quad\mbox{and}\quad e^x \sin y = e^u\sin v. $$
Does it follow that $(x,y) = (u,v)$? No. E.g take $x=u$, $y=0$ and $v=2\pi$.

For linear maps it is true that injectivity is equivalent to $f(x,y)= 0$ implies $(x,y) = 0$. Is your map $f$ linear, however?

Comment: thanks man, map is not linear.

Answer (score 5):

It is not surjective because$$(\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2):\|f(x,y)\|=e^x>0,$$and therefore you never have $f(x,y)=(0,0)$.